# Не могу установить tensorflow с помощью pip

Tags: python

Пытаюсь установить tensorflow через pip командой pip install tensorflow, но в итоге получаю ошибку:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TensorFlow` поддерживает только 64-битные версии `Python 3.5–3.7`.
<sub>*По состоянию на 18.04.2020.*</sub>

У Вас неподдерживаемая версия `Python`.

---

Попробуйте установить 64-битную версию `Python 3.7.7`: [Windows x86-64 executable installer](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.7/python-3.7.7-amd64.exe).

Comment: Да, у меня python 3.7.0 32-х битный. А как можно обновить на 64-битную версию?

Comment: @УмныйХачик Просто скачать её: [Windows x86-64 executable installer](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.7/python-3.7.7-amd64.exe).

Comment: спасибо, установил, всё работает)

Comment: @УмныйХачик Рад помочь :) Если ответ Вам помог, то Вы можете отметить его как верный, нажав на зелёную галочку слева.

Answer (score 0):

У меня python 3.9 и я смог легко установить на него tensorflow 2.7. можно попробовать повыше, но я думаю тебе хватит.
можно попробовать установить через pip3 install tensorflow==2.7, через == указывается версия, которую ты хочешь установить.

Comment: Вопросу уже почти 4 года, на тот момент скорее всего бинарных сборок tensorflow для Python 3.9 еще не было. Отвечать сейчас уже не имеет смысла, т.к. вопрос скорее всего уже не актуален.